# How to get the userid of a hidden telegram account?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I am writing through a translator, so I apologize in advance for inaccuracies. I will try to explain everything easily in words.

I’m developing a bot that

- Forwards a message from a user to a
  conversation with administrators (**forwardMessage** method).
- Admin needs to reply to the forwarded message.
- He clicks “Reply” and writes the text.

The problem is that if the link to the **user’s account is hidden** (*Settings - Confidentiality - Message Forwarding - "Nobody"*), then the bot **does not receive the account ID,** which is written inside the forward_from array.
The forward_from array is returned only if the account link is open.

At the same time, in the "**Livegram bot**" bot it is somehow implemented.

How to solve my problem?

Comment: Interesting to know